# Getting text enclosed by <li> tags

Tags: c#, winforms, html-agility-pack

Hi This is how  my html file look like

```
   <div class="panel-body sozluk">
                    <ol>
                        <li>kitap <code>isim</code> </li>

</span>             </ol>
    </div>
```

I am required to get values enclosed by the "li" tags.
This is my Xpath

```
//*[@id="wrap"]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.Load("word.html");

var v =  document.DocumentNode
                 .SelectNodes("//[@id='wrap']/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ol ")
                 .Select(x => x.ChildNodes["li"].InnerText);
```

Application crashes everytime.How can I do this

Comment: What is the exception – type *and* message – when it crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, your XPath is invalid because it missing the star symbol (`*`) at the beginning :

```
var v =  document.DocumentNode
                 .SelectNodes("//[@id='wrap']/div[2]/div[5]/....")
                                ^here, right after '//'
```

Such verbose XPath is fragile, always prefer selecting elements by id or class or some other attribute, possible example :

```
var v =  document.DocumentNode
                 .SelectNodes("//*[@id='wrap']//div[@class='panel-body sozluk']/ol/li")
                 .Select(o => o.InnerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your HTML first:

```
   <div class="panel-body sozluk">
                    <ol>
                        <li>kitap <code>isim</code> </li>

</span>             </ol>
    </div>
```

This is invalid. You have a `div`, inside which you have an `ol`, inside which you have a `li`, inside which you have a `code`. However, you are closing a `span` inside your `div`. The `span`, if opened at all was opened outside the `div` which contains the closing of the `span`. Make sure you are having valid html, before you try to extract things from it. And structure your code, I am sure you would have observed this problem if your code was structured.

Comment: exception message says "Expression must evaluate to a node-set."and @Lajos It must be valid html this is the link    http://www.seslisozluk.net/

Comment: It is invalid to add a closing </span> inside a div node. I really do not care about seslisozluk.net. And your expression is not evaluating to a node-set. That's another problem. Invalid HTML is invalid HTML even if it is taken from your favorite website.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is kinda messy, but if you don't mind using another package,
use [Fizzler for HTMLAgilityPack](https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/), that will allow you to use jquery-like selectors to get them instead of xpath.

```
var liList = document.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("li");
```

Comment: Side note: your CSS selector expression can also be translated to simple xpath : `document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li")`